# Does CakePHP play nice with Oracle? How about other frameworks?

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework, cakephp, frameworks

I'm just investigating some frameworks (CakePHP particularly) for a PHP project I'm about to start, and it must run on Oracle.

A quick googling found that Cake doesn't come packaged with Oracle support, and that there is [a driver someone wrote](http://jeff.loiselles.com/wordpress/?p=20), but that was back in April 2007, so I don't know how valid the information still is.

Has anyone had any experience with CakePHP or any other PHP Framework running over Oracle? Any pointers for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle is certainly one of the more neglected databases in Cake. There *is* an [Oracle driver](http://book.cakephp.org/view/87/DataSources) included by default which has even gone through [a number of revisions](https://trac.cakephp.org/log/branches/1.2.x.x/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_oracle.php?action=stop_on_copy&rev=8268&stop_rev=&mode=follow_copy), but there's very little [test coverage](https://trac.cakephp.org/browser/branches/1.2.x.x/cake/tests/cases/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_oracle.test.php) for it. Whether that makes the driver good or bad I can't say, it just means it hasn't gone through a whole lot of testing and possibly real-world usage yet.

Again, the driver may or may not be fine, but if it's a mission critical app, Cake probably isn't the best choice. Unless you're ready to jump in and fix the driver if necessary. (And contribute patches back to the Cake project. :o))

Answer (score 1):

CakePHPdoes como packaged with Oracle 8 and higher support, all you have to do is change de driver in your DATABASE CONFIG in `app/config/database.php`

```
 'driver' => 'oracle'
```

http://code.cakephp.org/source/app/config/database.php.default#82

Answer (score 1):

About other frameworks: We have an intranet running Zend Framework & Oracle db. Oracle (in general) sux :) No autoincrement, charset problems, filed-case related problems and other stuff, but the driver itself works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

May be these links can help you:

- https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/228
- http://book.cakephp.org/view/68/Creating-Database-Tables

Good luck.